# How do i get a form post to an external site to appear in an iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am using MVC and C#, I need to post a form to an external **payment** website. But i would like the result page to appear in an Iframe on my view.

```
<form id='myform' action="https://externalsite.somewhere" method="post" target="myframe">
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SomeData)
   @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MoreData)        
   <input type="submit" value="do it"/>
</form>
<iframe id="myframe" width="600px" height="600px"></iframe>
```

I could be going about this in the wrong way, i have never done this before so If you have any suggestions or advice on this i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create the `<iframe>` inside your view and have the `src` of this iframe pointing to a controller action that will serve a view containing this form. When the user submits the form he is redirected to the payment website inside the iframe.